# XML import into EXCEL via VBA doesnt refresh

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am trying to import an `XML` content into a excel via `macro`.

I have tried recording the steps and the automatic code created by `EXCEL VBA` is as below:

**code:**

```
Sub Macro4()
'
' Macro4 Macro
'

Sheets("Temp").Select
    Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
        "C:\Users\BERAAR1\Desktop\Utilization_matrix\Requests_Weekly.xml"
    Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("test.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("Temp").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Windows("Requests_Weekly.xml").Activate
    ActiveWindow.Close
End Sub
```

When I execute the macro again,that just reads only header and the content of the XML doesn't load into the excel.

Could you please recommend any tweaks to the code so that I can import XML into EXCEL without any issue ?

Comment: Can you post a snippet of XML so we can reproduce?

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub test_user2075017()
    ImportXML "C:\Users\BERAAR1\Desktop\Utilization_matrix\Requests_Weekly.xml"
End Sub
```

And the called sub:

```
Sub ImportXML(XML_Path As String)
    Dim wB As Workbook
    Set wB = Workbooks.Open(filename:=XML_Path)
    With wB.Sheets(1)
        .Range(.Range("A1"), _
               .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.count,"A").End(xlUp).Row, _
                      .Cells(1,.Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column)).Copy
    End With 'wB.Sheets(1)

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Temp")
        .Cells.Clear
        .Range("A1").Paste
    End With 'ThisWorkbook.Sheets ("Temp")

    MsgBox wB.Name & " was imported in sheet : Temp", vbOKOnly + vbInformation
    wB.Close False
End Sub
```

Comment: I am getting error `Run time error#:438` `object doesnt support the property or method` and when clicked on debug it directs me to the `.Range("A1").Paste` code.Please advise @R3uK

Comment: @user2075017 : Try the edit. If you still have an error, how many rows do you have in your XML? Do you have enough in the Excel sheet you want to paste into?

Comment: I am still getting the same `object doesnt support the property` error with the above code.My XML is a dynamic workbook that is exported from Dynamics CRM tool and its on an average of 1K records each time the sheet is opened and refreshed..I am sure the target sheet has the sufficient rows..